# Why is javascript variable undefined if it prints to console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand JS better. I have defined a variable test, where I attempted to update it inside the function in order for it to take the value of the list of an object contained in a variable, mySum. Despite this printing to the console correctly, mySum prints undefined when tested in the final line to see if it's updated. Can I get some guidance on what I'm doing incorrectly with respect to updating the global variable, test?

```
var test;
    knex("my_table").sum("funds").where("user_id",2)
    .then(function (mySum){
        return mySum;
    })
    .then(function (mySum){
        knex("my_table").select("funds").where("funds",mySum[0]['sum'])
        .bind(console)
        .then(console.log)
        test = mySum;
    });
console.log(test);
```

Edit: I understand it now. To use this within the EJS something like this would need to be constructed to get two variables representing funds for two different users in this case...

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    knex("my_table").sum("funds").where("user_id",2)
    .then(function(mySum){
        knex("my_table").sum("funds").where("user_id",3)
        .then(function(mySum2){
        res.render("home", {
        page_title: 'home',
        mySum: mySum[0]['sum'],
        mySum2: mySum2[0]['sum']
        });
        })

    });
```

Comment: You probably should read about asynchronous programming to better understand the problem with your code.

Comment: Hint: `console.log` is being called before `test = mySum`;

Comment: `.then()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Guys, this is the COMMENTS section. It is for COMMENTS. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have commented, `console.log(test)` fires prior to `test = mySum` because your code is asynchronous. The `.then` is a promise that fires when the prior code completes but the rest of the code will continue to process in the meantime. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is some documentation regarding promises in JavaScript.

Comment: After reading through the document, I attempted the following `function sums(){
         var val = await knex("my_table").sum("funds").where("user_id",2)
        .then(function(value){
         return value;
        
    });
    return val;
    };
    var test2 = sums();
    console.log(test2," test2");` but am getting `var test2 = async function sums(){
                      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function `